# undefined local variable or method Ruby

Tags: ruby

Я делаю самые первые шаги в Ruby и у меня возникла такая проблема:

```
class Metods
  def accelerate
    puts "Stepping on the gas"
    puts "Speeding up"
  end
  accelerate
end
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/Admin/my/metods.rb
C:/Users/Admin/my/metods.rb:6:in `<class:Metods>': undefined local variable or method `accelerate' for Metods:Class (NameError)
    from C:/Users/Admin/my/metods.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем проблема, думал, может функция должна что-то возвращать, делал return - не работает все равно.
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Metods
  def accelerate
    puts "Stepping on the gas"
    puts "Speeding up"
  end  
end

newclass = Metods.new

newclass.accelerate
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
undefined local variable or method `accelerate' for Metods:Class
```

Ну ведь и правда, **у класса этого метода нет**.

Метод `accelerate`, что вы определили, будет у **объектов этого класса**. Можно создать такой  с помощью `Metods.new`.

---

*Хотя должен отметить, что для класса это очень странное название, оно характерно скорее для модулей.*

Answer (score 1):

Вызывая метод `accelearte` внутри класса вы фактически выполняете вызов `Metods.accelerate`. Чтобы он сработал, метод должен быть объявлен как метод класса, а не инстанс-метод

```
class Metods
  def self.accelerate
    puts "Stepping on the gas"
    puts "Speeding up"
  end
  accelerate
end

# Metods.accelerate
```

Или вы не должны вызывать метод у класса, а вызывать его уже у объекта (тогда ваше определение метода будет корректным)

```
class Metods
  def accelerate
    puts "Stepping on the gas"
    puts "Speeding up"
  end
end

obj = Metods.new
obj.accelerate
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать инстанс-метод accelearte так как хочешь ты можно при помощи другого инстанса например: 
class Metods
  def accelerate
    puts "Stepping on the gas"
    puts "Speeding up"
  end
  def start_accelerate
    accelerate
  end
end
new_class = Metods.new
new_class.start_accelerate